# last entry in a loop

Tags: smarty

I have an associative array and I generate a lot of different things with this array.

The output I need has the form

```
aa, ab, ac, ad, af, ak, az
```

So the last entry does not have a comma after it

```
{section name=i loop=$aColums}
  {if $aColums[i].contshow eq 'y'}
    {$aColums[i].Name}
  {endif}
{/section}
```

My problem is that I don't know when I've reached the last value, which has the `contshow=y` attribute. So my next thought was to apply the comma before I write `aColums[i].Name`. But here I have a similar problem becuase I don't know when I've reached the first value with `contshow=y`.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative method, using the section's .last property.

```
{section name=i loop=$aColums} 
  {if $aColums[i].contshow eq 'y'} 
    {$aColums[i].Name}{if $smarty.section.i.last eq false}, {/if}
  {endif} 
{/section}
```

This adds a ', ' after every output Name - unless it's the last iteration of the `{section}`.  I'm assuming that your $aColums array data doesn't already have commas tacked on.

You also have another option - pregenerate this string in PHP using implode:

```
$aColumsString = implode(', ', $aColums);
$smarty->assign('aColumsString', $aColumsString);
```

Then just output to the template as needed.  If you require the list with commas more than once, this is probably the more efficient method.  If you need it once, it's probably a toss-up effiency-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to deal with this is to write the commas *before* each element.  In this way, the special-case is the *first* element (which doesn't need a preceding comma) rather than the last, and it's a lot easier to work out whether you're seeing the first element or not.  Just set a boolean flag to `true` initially, then set it to `false` after matching an entry.

Mind you, Smarty might have a utility function for "joining" the array with a given string (comma, in this case).  If such a function exists, using it directly would be the best option.

Comment: maybe i do something wrong, but after i assign a value it seems that smarty will not change it {assign var="tv" value="false"} and in match case

Answer (score 0):

In Smarty 3, this is much simplified:

```
{foreach $aColumns AS $aCol}
    {$aCol}{if not $aCol@last}, {/if}
{/foreach}
```